# AWS EC2: Secure configuration via IP access list

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip

My company have a network with a fixed IP address/IP address range. Is it save when I configure my Security group that all traffic from this IP address will be accepted and everything else will be blocked?
Especially, is it possible that someone fake my IP address and gets access to all the open ports on my system?

Regards, Johannes.

Answer (score 1):

No one will fake your IP range to get pass a firewall. The only way to do this is easily if your app is all UDP.

That said just allowing your office's IP in is the first start. You might want to expand on that as the company grows. Like does everyone in the office need access to the whole AWS VPC? If not then you are looking at site to site VPN connection from your office to the VPC. This allows you to not even expose anything. Its like the VPC is in a room in the office. You can setup VLANs in the office to only allow certain vlans access to certain parts of the VPC.